# Google polyline high memory useage?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, cefsharp, google-polyline

The following function is called each second. The purpose is to update the last point on the polyline to follow a marker. The problem is, each time the code runs, the memory usage of the browser (CefSharp) increases by around 1 MB constantly, going from around 50 MB to over 200 MB in just a few minutes.

```
function moveMarker(lat, lon, hdg, followme) {
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

    var len = traceLine.getPath().length;
    traceLine.getPath().removeAt(len-1);
    traceLine.getPath().push(marker.getPosition());
}
```

By removing the last three lines, the memory usage remains stable at around 53 MB.

The function running this code is invoked from C# using the following code:

```
String js = String.Format("moveMarker('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');",
            lat.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            lon.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), hdg,
            followMeCb.Checked ? "true" : "false");

myChromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(js);
```

Am I doing something totally wrong here?

Comment: How does `Chrome` behave? What version of `CefSharp` are you using? `WinForms`, `WPF`? `x86`, `x64`? You know the basic stuff needed for any bug report.....

Comment: I'm using the WinForms x86 version. It seems to be a CefSharp issue, as the memory usage seems normal when I run it in Chrome.

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about what version I had, but it was from january some time, so might be 45. Updating to the latest stable version of CefSharp (49.0.0) seems to have solved the issue.